# How to disable the dtls stuff in OpenSSL 1.0.2k?

Tags: build, openssl

I am trying to configure the OpenSSL 1.0.2k for windows.

According to https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation, I can use

perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm no-dtls

But it shows me error unknown dtls command.
[image]

Can anyone help me please how to disable the DTLS in OpenSSL 1.0.2 branch.

Comment: Does (1) the library build afterwards, and (2) is `OPENSSL_NO_DTLS` defined in `opensslconf.h`? Also, please remove the picture and add the text. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: Yes, Library built afterwards successfully, and OPENSSL_NO_DTLS is not found in opensslconf.h @jww

Comment: It sounds like a minor issue with the Configure script. OpenSSL recently moved their bug tracking to the [OpenSSL GitHub](https://github.com/openssl/openssl). Maybe you could let them know about it.

Answer (score 1):

The option you want in OpenSSL 1.0.2 is `no-dtls1` (OpenSSL 1.1.0 has slightly different options in this area).

There is a bug for this option, so you will still see the `unknown option - no-dtls1` message appear. However this is spurious. You can safely continue to build. You can confirm that DTLS has successfully been disabled by attempting to use it in `s_server`. It should complain because it doesn't understand the `-dtls` option:

```
cd out32dll
openssl s_server -dtls
usage: s_server [args ...]

 -accept arg   - port to accept on (default is 4433)
 -verify_hostname host - check peer certificate matches "host"
 -verify_email email - check peer certificate matches "email"
 -verify_ip ipaddr - check peer certificate matches "ipaddr"
...
```

EDIT:
Note that a fix for the spurious `unknown option - no-dtls1` warning message has been committed to the OpenSSL git repo here:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/1c5ebcd87822c2af4b8fdc23fa8b9a7201fb7097